# UNION SELECT, parallelization and IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, identity

There are four identical staging tables:

```
CREATE TABLE s_table_1
(
      id INT IDENTITY(1, 4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , some_data NVARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE s_table_2
(
      id INT IDENTITY(2, 4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , some_data NVARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE s_table_3
(
      id INT IDENTITY(3, 4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , some_data NVARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE s_table_4
(
      id INT IDENTITY(4, 4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , some_data NVARCHAR(100)
);
```

Subsequently, they are used in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW s_table AS
              SELECT * FROM dbo.s_table_1
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM dbo.s_table_2
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM dbo.s_table_3
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM dbo.s_table_4;
```

The rationale behind this structure is to be able to stage data in four parallel streams to make use of multi-core CPU on the server (data comes from a large flat text file from a local drive; reading that file it is much, much faster than writing rows to target table; splitting this to four streams gives me over 3x faster ETL and I need this to be fast)

I need the ID values to be unique across all four staging tables - this is why I created them as IDENTITY(N, 4) where N is 1, 2, 3 or 4, respectively.

Is this setup "risky" in terms of uniqueness? I mean, is there any chance that one of those four IDENTITY columns clashes with another one?

Any hints welcome.

SQL Server 2012

Comment: I did some basic tests with deleting data, truncating table and new inserts and so on and everything went well. Seems ok to me, creative approach.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2012 you are able to use sequences instead of Identity for such scenarios.
[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

However SQL Server uses all cores unless you cap with using maxdop. A performance benefit would be if you store the tables on different filegroups on different drives to increase read performance.

Comment: I only write to that table and never read from it (at least, not during the ETL). Not too familiar with the internals of the engine but I can tell there's a significant difference in performance between writing to a single table and writing to 4 separate tables even though they are located in the same filegroup / disk. To observe it, you just need the source (here: flat text file) to be much faster to read than the target can accept. I believe SQL Server splits workload between cores but the ETL engine does not, unless you build separate flows yourself.